# CakePdf won't generate pdf file inside a folder

Tags: cakephp, pdf

Im using cakepdf for generating pdf files using wkhtmltopdf and it works, the issue is when i wanted to create pdf files inside a folder it shows me this exception :

```
System error <pre>Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError </pre>
```

Here's the code Im using for generating the pdf file :

```
$CakePdf = new CakePdf();
$CakePdf->template('mynote','default');
//get the pdf string returned
$pdf = $CakePdf->output();
//or write it to file directly
$pdf = $CakePdf->write(APP . 'webroot'. DS .'files' . DS . 'mynote.pdf');
```

and for the pdf template i used mynote.ctp that only contains this code inside pdf folder

```
<div>Hello</div>
```

After some hustle i disbaled this error by commenting the code inside output functions but still i can't get the style and the images,like i use to.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2051**

Comment: I Managed to make it working , I had to modify the wkhtmltoPDF class inside the plugin i disabled the errors the errors and it worked, but the problem it doesn't fetch the images and css.

Comment: thanks with this link and some of what i've done it worked finally, i've imported everything from a website url.